# Application Logic - Only allow one admin user to use app

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a very tricky situation right now..

I have an application which downloads the email attachments of a particular email account, and then saves those attachment to a specified folder. The application also has some features, like sort the attachments by date, sort by keywords, etc.

So the app has two key features:

**Email Attachment Download**

**Sorting**

*The requirement:*

Only **ONE** `administrator` can run both features, and the `normal users` can only run the **sorting feature**

*The Problem:*

If there are two administrator accounts, how can I limit it to one only?
I only have one useful code as of now..

```
If My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator) Then
   MsgBox("I have admin privileges")
Else
   MsgBox("I do not have admin privileges")
End If
```

I just need to know if other admins are using the app. If one admin already ran the app, other admins can't run it anymore..only 1 instance of the app should run for all admins.. thanks.

Comment: Please change the question title to an appropriate title

Answer (score 1):

Why not Create one application level variable to keep count

```
AdminLoggedinCount
```

default to 0 and +1 when app starts

```
If My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator) Then
    If AdminLoggedinCount >=1
      MsgBox("try again later another admin is using now")
   Else
      MsgBox("I have admin privileges")
   End if
Else
   MsgBox("I do not have admin privileges")
End If
```

Comment: this logic sounds cool.. you can store one flag colum in database as well to just check whether any admin is logged in or not...

Comment: yes why not variable value via DB is much better approach, except you for the instance where app crashes (instead of normal close) and the value is not reset.

Comment: sure, all the best, will be curious to know if this helped ? or how you solved it.. encourage you to mark as answer / up vote / post your new solution -- this will help someone someday.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by doing with a simple Semaphore file.  The basic premise, when the application starts, and user is an admin user, try to open a file to a common location visible by all users.  if the file exsits, try to erase it, in case the other user may have aborted out and did not properly close and erase the file.

If the file can not be deleted, then an admin is STILL active with the file open.  When the user is finished, close and erase the file...

You could have a variable in the app for the status that the semaphore file is theirs (or not), and to allow (or not) the special extra feature.

Again, the file could be as simple as...

X:\YourSharePath\ActiveAdminUser.txt

Comment: hey thanks :D I think the problem with this is when the app crashes and fails to delete the sema file.. but this one is good too :D

Comment: @Codemunkeee, that's the whole point... if the person crashes, the file handle would be released, that's why I pointed out to try and erase the file first.  If still used, then someone STILL has it, otherwise, they crashed, you erase it, and create a new one for yourself to continue until your turn is done.

Comment: wouldnt it be much safer to play with DB and use lock instead of relaying on file ? app releases lock releases automatically

Comment: @BaljeetsinghSucharia, they were looking for A solution, there could be many, but the principle still applies, if a file, or a table/record lock.